# White Space Between Divs

Tags: css, cross-browser, spaces

Stuck on an HTML cross browser issue. Site built by many, so messy, but must get up asap!

Each 4 page layouts of the site vary and handled by different classes, but when change the margin or padding, it gives me blank spaces between my divs. ???  Why and how to fix if anyone knows please!

Thanks.

Comment: Ok - the margin and padding properties adds space around your elements, its what they do. You need to be more specific in your problem for a specific answer. I can help if you provide HTML and CSS examples.

Comment: for such "messy" work I would go back and implement a CSS Framework to help not only the sizing, measurments and easy to deply and change as well cross browser issues would never appear.

Answer (score 1):

Just guessing here because I can't see your code, but you probably need to also modify the `width`s.

For example, if you add `margin-left: 10px`, then also reduce the `width` by `10px`.